# Doctrine Performance On OneToMany RelationShip

Tags: php, performance, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I am wondering whether OneToMany Realationship will hamper on application's performance. Say, city and user entity are in a OneToMany relationship, that means, a city can contain a lots of users. Now after setting the relationship in entity classes, whenever I retrieve a city, I can get its users via:

```
$users = $city->getUsers();
```

Now, I am wondering about the internal architechture. Whenever I retrieve city, will it query for all users also? If so, lets say a city can have 10000 users. Now won't it be a performance issue that I am retrieving a city only, but its getting along with all 10000 users as well? Or, it uses some other machanism and I am totally ok with it to implement?

Wish to get an explanation from you experts and suggestions about best practices regarding this situations as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not an expert, but I can share you some good practices that you could consider at application development:

#### fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"

By default, doctrine 2.0 will load the entire collection and store it memory. In a scenario like yours, the users collection could be a performance problems by the table dimesion. So, why not mark the relationship as EXTRA_LAZY? An entity with this fetch mode only will be load when is accessed without triggering a full load of the collection.

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="cities", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
```

Allowing this fetch mode, you are able to make use of function like `slide()` and `count()` robustly. For example:

```
$users = $em->getRepository('models\User')->findAll();
echo  $users->count();
```

The code triggers a sql statement like `select count(*) from users..` instead looping through the $user collection.

#### Hydrating objects

Not always is necessary to load a collection of entities. If you are creating a blog system, we need to provide only a list of post titles. This infrasrtucture can be inproved by [Hydrating objects](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats) for read-only purposes.

#### Useful links

Some links that routes you to official doctrine docs guide.

- [Improving performance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/improving-performance.html)
- [Doctrine 2, best practices](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html)